# extracting multiple values from xml file using R

Tags: r, xml

Here is a small example of the XML file I'm working with. I would like to extract the number of auctions that have a seller rating greater than 150.  Does anyone know how i go about doing this?

```
<root>
        <listing>
            <seller_info>
                <seller_name>seller12</seller_name>
                <seller_rating>100</seller_rating>
            </seller_info>
            <payment_types>
                Visa
            </payment_types>
            <shipping_info>
                Buyer pays shipping charges.
            </shipping_info>
            <buyer_protection_info></buyer_protection_info>
            <auction_info>
                <current_bid>$820.00</current_bid>
                <time_left>4 days, 18 hours +</time_left>
                <high_bidder>
                    <bidder_name>gosha555@example.com</bidder_name>
                    <bidder_rating>-2</bidder_rating>
                </high_bidder>
                <num_items>1</num_items>
                <num_bids>12</num_bids>
                <started_at>$1.00</started_at>
                <bid_increment></bid_increment>
                <notes></notes>
            </auction_info>
        </listing>
        <listing>
            <seller_info>
                <seller_name>seller50</seller_name>
                <seller_rating>200</seller_rating>
            </seller_info>
            <payment_types>
                Visa
            </payment_types>
            <shipping_info>
                Buyer pays shipping charges.
            </shipping_info>
            <buyer_protection_info></buyer_protection_info>
            <auction_info>
                <current_bid>$920.00</current_bid>
                <time_left>4 days, 17 hours +</time_left>
                <high_bidder>
                    <bidder_name>seller50@example.com</bidder_name>
                    <bidder_rating>-2</bidder_rating>
                </high_bidder>
                <num_items>1</num_items>
                <num_bids>5</num_bids>
                <started_at>$1.00</started_at>
                <bid_increment></bid_increment>
                <notes></notes>
            </auction_info>
        </listing>  
<root>
```

So far I have parsed this data using `xmlTreeParse` and used `xpathSapply`

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("ebay.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
log <- xpathSApply(doc, '//*/seller_rating')
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your attempted code? And what is desired result?

Comment: @Parfait The problem is i am extracting all auctions with a seller rating, not just the auctions with a seller rating greater than 150. I would just like to output the number of auctions that have seller ratings > 150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your code is also getting the tag.  If you use:

```
SellerRatings = xmlSApply(doc["//listing//seller_info//seller_rating"], xmlValue)
```

You will just get the values,  so you can count them.

```
sum(SellerRatings > 150)
```

Or briefly

```
sum(xmlSApply(doc["//*//seller_rating"], xmlValue) > 150)
```

Comment: Thanks @G5W. When I try your code, I am getting this error : `Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLNodeSet"`

Comment: It is xpathSApply   It has an S

Comment: weird, I am using an S. `doc <- xmlTreeParse("ebay.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
log <- xpathSApply(doc["//listing//seller_info//seller_rating"], xmlValue)`

Comment: Doh.  I am not reading carefully.  NOT `xpathSApply`   Should be `xmlSApply`